# Consequences of a false magic tattoo

Tags: science-based, biology, medical

Silly question (you've been warned).

Let's say the magic users of my world devised a way to place lasting charms on people - by tattooing them. That process involves specifically prepared inks involving spell components, notably crushed gems. Now, they perfected that process, so it's safe if done by someone who actually studied the procedure and is being careful.

But arcane studies requires... well, studying, and not everyone can afford the money or time to be trained in the mystical arts. Let's say some yahoo with a poke stick, no brain and zero magic knowledge hears about the process and go "Oh, I can *totally* crush gemstones and put the powder in my ink to make magic tattoos!"<sup>1</sup>

I would assume this is *bad*<sup>2</sup>, but apparently, it's not a trivial question (see "[road tattoos](https://www.webmd.com/first-aid/what-to-know-road-rash)") since you can have foreign object stuck under your skin with minimal consequences<sup>3</sup>. **What range of consequences should we expect from such a procedure?**

Please, answer based on actual-real world medicine, no magic involved here, only regular biology. As pointed in comment and for the sake of narrowing it down, let's restrict the list to precious stones (diamond, ruby, sapphire and emerald as per [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemstone)).

<sub>1: Yeah, that's a very dumb idea. Which means someone is bound to do it.

2: I know a bit about tattoos infections, having been tattooed.

3: I looked online, but believe it or not, nobody bothered to make a studies about precious stone in tattoo and long lasting effects. Lots of conflicting results.</sub>

Comment: It looks like you're wanting us to brainstorm answers to a question involving magical consequences. Questions asking for unbounded lists like this tend to be very broad and attract many opinion based answers. Please remember that if a question has many valid answers than it's probably too broad for this site.

Comment: It's specifically said **"Please, answer based on actual-real world medicine, no magic involved here, only regular biology."** and tagged [science-based], [biology] and [medicine].

Comment: So in essence you're asking what can go wrong with a tattoo?

Comment: What gems specifically? Since there are thousands of gem types it gets a bit unwieldy as a question, can you narrow it lots?  Also worth looking at what inks are already [made of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane_clathrate#Reservoir_size) - there's plenty of toxic stuff to chose from. Perhaps decide what effects you might like and then we could help you find something that fits.

Comment: sphennings - I'm sorry, I am perhaps not expressing myself properly. Tattoos consequences are fairly easy to research and I wouldn't bother you with that. The question is "what happens if you put mineral that has no business being in your tattoo ink in your tattoo ink and uses it to tattoo someone?". Is it clearer worded that way?

Comment: That's still pretty broad, as A Rogue Ant mentions. But it's much more specific than my first, or second readings of the question.

Comment: Rogue Ant - Narrowed it down, thanks for the pointer. However, your link is to Methane clathrate, and I supposed it's not what you meant to link to?

Comment: Oh, ha! That was in my clipboard from hours ago, I meant to post [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tattoo_ink#Pigment_bases), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Instead of (or *aside*) a science-based tag, you need a magic tag. A tattoo consists of a small amount of ink injected under the skin. Contamination can cause irritations and itch.. and worst case poisoning, depending on the exact chemical composition of these magic gemstones. But there is no science-based reasoning, allowing for these "gemstones" to be magical. When you would  leave out the "magic" this question is about safety of tattoos.. and better put elsewhere ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the [health consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_effects_of_tattoos) of regular tattoos and low-quality tattoos, not many, even fewer.

Aluminum oxide, the main component of [rubies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby) and [sapphires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire) is considered inert (and [frequently used for implants](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12504517/) with essentially no ill effects).

Emerald is basically a [silicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald), which is also largely inert with regards to being under your skin (or even over your skin or in your mouth - silicates are common ingredients in cosmetics). It would be an occupational hazard for the person crushing the gems and preparing the pigments as they're exposed to the dust

Diamond is basically pure carbon in a crystalline form, which makes it also very inert.

Depending on the quality level of the gems and the pigment made with them, I'd expect some [allergic contact dermatitis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allergic_contact_dermatitis) if the gems in question contain traces of other elements like nickel, chromium, or even gold, AND the person receiving the tattoo is allergic

Comment: I'd be careful saying silicates are inert. Silicosis is a form of occupational lung disease caused by inhalation of crystalline silica dust.

Comment: @L.Dutch That would be an occupational hazard of the person preparing the pigment more than the person receiving the tattoo, I'll include that in the answer, but I don't expect skin reactions (as it would be the equivalent of having very small grains of sand under your skin)

Comment: "not many, even fewer." I wouldn't be _that_ sure. Maybe avoid [Cinnabar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnabar) (mercury),[Crocoite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocoite) (lead and hexavalent chromium), [Legrandite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legrandite) (arsenic), [Mimetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimetite) (lead and arsenic), [Realgar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realgar) (arsenic), [Stolzite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolzite) (lead). Plus a good amount of copper based gemstones - not necessary toxic in small doses but not very good for your health in larger amounts.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi That's a good addition, but I'm only discussing the 4 gems OP listed in the answer. Also note that many of those minerals you mention WERE used in the past for regular tattoos